# how to resolve Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger where if the total number of customer reaches 10 then it should raise an error

This is my plsql code:

```
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_count_check
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON customer2
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  count_customer NUMBER(5);
  6  BEGIN
  7  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_customer FROM customer2
  8           WHERE cusid = :new.cusid;
  9  IF count_customer > 10 THEN
 10   Raise_application_error(-20000,'Maximum customer count:' ||
 11               count_customer || 'reached');
 12  ENDIF;
 13  END;
 14  /
```

and this is the warning I'm getting:

> ```
> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
>
> SQL> SHOW ERROR; 
> Errors for TRIGGER CUSTOMER_COUNT_CHECK:
>
> LINE/COL ERROR
> -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
> 10/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
>          following:
>          if
> ```

Comment: I changed it... actually I mixed it with another code that's why the name of the variable was different..

Comment: It's `end if` not `endif`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-1D6FD34F-F58B-4D0B-B7FC-F7C2C22377C3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_count_check
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON customer2
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  count_customer NUMBER(5);
  6  BEGIN
  7  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_customer FROM customer2
  8           WHERE cusid = :new.cusid;
  9  IF count_customer > 10 THEN
 10   Raise_application_error(-20000,'Maximum customer count:' ||
 11               count_customer || 'reached');
 12  END IF;
 13  END;
 14  /
```

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes also wish the error messages would be more clear.

In line 12:

Wrong

```
ENDIF;
```

Right:

```
END IF;
```

Also the line counting is sometimes not so intuitive. It says 10/4 while it seems to be 12/4. But the first 2 lines are not considered part of the triggers code and so the counting is line 10 column 4.